# Memorycache won't store my object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, memorycache

So I've written a couple of wrapper methods around the System.Runtime MemoryCache, to get a general/user bound cache context per viewmodel in my ASP.NET MVC application.

At some point i noticed that my delegate just keeps getting called every time rather than retrieving my stored object for no apparent reason.

Oddly enough none of my unit tests (which use simple data to check it) failed or showed a pattern explaining that.

Here's one of the wrapper methods:

```
    public T GetCustom<T>(CacheItemPolicy cacheSettings, Func<T> createCallback, params object[] parameters)
    {
        if (parameters.Length == 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("GetCustom can't be called without any parameters.");

        lock (_threadLock)
        {
            var mergedToken = GetCacheSignature(parameters);
            var cache = GetMemoryCache();
            if (cache.Contains(mergedToken))
            {
                var cacheResult = cache.Get(mergedToken);
                if (cacheResult is T)
                    return (T)cacheResult;

                throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("A caching signature was passed, which duplicates another signature of different return type. ({0})", mergedToken));
            }

            var result = createCallback(); <!-- keeps landing here
            if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(result, default(T)))
            {
                cache.Add(mergedToken, result, cacheSettings);
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
```

I was wondering if anyone here knows about conditions which render an object invalid for storage within the MemoryCache.

Until then i'll just strip my complex classes' properties until storage works.

Experiences would be interesting nevertheless.

Comment: @Andreas Experience - I set a fixed expiry datetime in the constructor so all my unit tests passed and then on production, after the date passed, I stopped being able to cache anything. Sounds similar. Check cache settings are providing a sensible (and future!) expiry date on every cache.Add() call

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov ASP.NET MVC 5.2

Comment: @Kaido The method in question does pass DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMinutes(5) as absolute expiry date at all times. So it should not be that. Thanks anyway

Comment: @Andreas does that datetime get kept in a property that is kept for more than 5 minutes?

Comment: @Kaido it's potentially new with every call. In my tests it works just fine. Once it can't find a corresponding cached element it'll just execute the delegate and store that object with the passed policy. The problem is that for some reason it won't work with my complex type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are couple frequent reasons why it may be happening (assuming correct logic to actually add objects to cache/find correct cache instance):

- x86 (32bit) process have "very small" amount of memory to deal with - it is relatively easy to consume too much memory outside the cache (or particular instance of the cache) and as result items will be immediately evicted from the cache.
- ASP.Net app domain recycles due to variety of reasons will clear out cache too.

Notes

- generally you'd store "per user cached information" in session state so it managed appropriately and can be persisted via SQL/other out-of-process state options.
- relying on caching per-user objects may not improve performance if you need to support larger number of users. You need to carefully measure impact on the load level you expect to have.

Comment: I've tried to attach a removed delegate to detect those evictions asap. (because i read it in another question). Do you think that there may be an occasion where the memorycache immediately declines the object and does not fire the removed event?

Comment: @AndreasMüller I don't know, but would not be surprised if it is the case - way too many people try to immediately re-insert object into cache on expiration... If you are interested try to look through the code - http://referencesource.microsoft.com/

Comment: Yeah. I'll have a look at that. Judging by the way things look you may be pointing in the right direction sadly.

Comment: My development environment is in a rather memory starved VM. Whenever i ran my test cases that memory was enough. However when starting the web application my memoryconsumption got big enough to trigger the threshold of immediate eviction. Thanks.